# Sending hierarchy of form fields in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, yii

For eg. I have form with many fields with `name="person[][name]"`.
Each person have many phone number fields (`name="person[][phone][]"`).

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="person[][name]" />  
    <input type="text" name="person[][phone][]" /> 
    <input type="text" name="person[][phone][]" /> 
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="person[][name]" />  
    <input type="text" name="person[][phone][]" /> 
    <input type="text" name="person[][phone][]" /> 
  </fieldset>

  ....

</form>
```

I want to get this on the server:

```
person[0][name]='John';
person[0][phone][0]='123';
person[0][phone][1]='234';
...
person[n][name]='Sam';
person[n][phone][0]='584';
person[n][phone][1]='697';
...
```

But now, I have:

```
person[0][name]='John';
person[1][phone][0]='123';
person[2][phone][1]='234';
...
person[n][name]='Sam';
person[n+1][phone][0]='584';
person[n+2][phone][1]='697';
...
```

How to solve this problem? Are there any solutions in Yii?

**P.S. My form is generated through JS.=( Every new person or phone is added by clicking on the button with jQuery.clone() function**

Comment: Can you add your form?

Comment: Is your form static like that or generated through php?